# Wix version 3.1.0.20 is considered as older than the 3.0.0.8559

Tags: jenkins, wix

We recently migrated from TFS build to jenkins server. Everything went fine(well, everything is now fine) except the version of the setup.

We now set the version to be the 3.1.0.X, X being the jenkins build number, previously we were having the 3.0.0.X, X being the TFS build number.

Obviously, the build number is much higher on TFS than on jenkins, but since the minor version is higher, it should be considered as more recent no?

How can I sort this out? To have my jenkins build being able to uninstall the TFS build?

Comment: The versions are seems to be good, are you sure the msi gets the build number?

Comment: Yes, because when I launch the wix setup, it is the version that I get displayed at least(and the ones that are available in the "programs" of the configuration panel

Comment: Is the upgrade code is the same? What the logs say regarding detecting installed package?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky Yes, it's the same upgradeCode(it a fixed value, and both jenkins and TFS were using the same code). What logs are you talking about? Is there specific logs that I can find for this kind of things?

Comment: As I understand you are trying to upgrade your product from v3.0.0(TFS) to 3.1.0 (Jenkins). The logs refer to the second installation.

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky But where do I find this log?

Comment: In %temp% folder, MSIXXXX X-random number, or run from command line: msiexec /i "Path to msi" /L*V "Path to log"